# How to get expression from string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Here is the string :'(a+b)+(x/y)*1000' 
from that string i want to get '(x/y)' meaning i want the part that contains the division to check later if denominator <> 0 to avoid division by zero.

The string formula can vary but divisions are always between parenthesis.

How can i achieve that in sql ?

Comment: i tried to extract the division part with substring function i could get the string until first parenthesis after '/' but i can't find out how to get string until first parenthesis before '/' ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bits that it appears you already have *(based on a comment you made)*...

- Pos of the `'/'` = `CHARINDEX('/', yourString)`
- Pos of the `')'` = `CHARINDEX(')', yourString, CHARINDEX('/', yourString) + 1)`

The position of the `(` is a little different, as you need to search backwards.  So you need to reverse the string.  And so you also need to change the starting position.

- `CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(yourString), LEN(yourString) - CHARINDEX('/', yourString) + 2)`

Which give the position from the right hand side.  `LEN(yourString) - position + 1` give the position from the left hand side.

Add that all together and you get a very long formula...

```
SUBSTRING(
  yourString,
    LEN(yourString)
  - CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(yourString), LEN(yourString) - CHARINDEX('/', yourString) + 2)
  + 1,
    CHARINDEX(')', yourString, CHARINDEX('/', yourString) + 1)
  - LEN(yourString)
  + CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(yourString), LEN(yourString) - CHARINDEX('/', yourString) + 2)
  - 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove everything up to the second `(` using `stuff` and get the characters to the next `)` using `left`.

```
declare @S varchar(20)
set @S = '(1+2)+(3/4)*1000'

select left(S2.S, charindex(')', S2.S)-1)
from (select stuff(@S, 1, charindex('(', @S), '')) as S1(S)
  cross apply (select stuff(S1.S, 1, charindex('(', S1.S), '')) as S2(S)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply it is instructive but i want the substring that contains the parenthesis meaning i want to extract (x/y) part not just the denominator

Comment: But if you are checking for division by zero you only need the value after `/` right?

Comment: yes but the first point is to extract that part to do other stuff i need to check division by zero too that's why i gave your answer one up